# Firestore: Conditional query not executed

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

This logs the snapshot:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const collection = db.collection(`companies/${company}/meetings`);
let query = collection.where('start', '>=', new Date());
const snapshot = await query.limit(10).get();
console.log(snapshot);
```

This doesn't:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const collection = db.collection(`companies/${company}/meetings`);
let query = collection.where('start', '>=', new Date());
if (branch) {
  query = query.where('branch', '==', branch);
}
const snapshot = await query.limit(10).get();
console.log(snapshot);
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Do you have the corresponding index? Do you get an error message if you put your code in a try/catch block?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thanks for your help! It was the missing index. I didn't catch it before because I wasn't showing errors in my console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are combining the `'>='` and `'=='` operators, Firestore needs to build an index for this query.

If you catch the error with a try/catch block, you will see the corresponding error, and, even better, [the error message includes a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message).

See the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview) for more details on indexing in Firestore.